# Typeclass of a polymorphic type suffers from type erasure

Tags: scala, typeclass, type-erasure, higher-kinded-types

Given a polymorphic type *Distribution*, I want to establish, what I would call a typeclass on this (polymorphic) type. I think this goes under the term Higer Kinded Types.

```scala
trait Distribution[A] extends Measure[A] with Random[A] {
  type Domain = A
}
```

Distributions instantiating this typeclass should implement a method train, which given a List of elements in the domain of the distribution, return an object this distribution.

```scala
trait ML[D <: Distribution[_] ] {
  def train( samples: List[D#Domain] ): D
}
```

But when I try to instantiate like this (Binomial is a Distribution[Int]):

```scala
implicit object MLBinomial extends ML[Binomial] {
  def train( samples: List[Int] ) : Binomial = ???
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Binomial.scala:181: object creation impossible, since method train in trait ML
of type (samples: List[_$1])org.lanyard.dist.disc.Binomial is not defined
(Note that List[_$1] does not match List[Int]: their type parameters differ)
```

I am guessing I am the victim of type erasure but I am not sure and just learning to fight with the scala type system. Is anybody able to fix this code or am I forced to use a different design?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you accepted the answer or provide more info in case something were still amiss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're defining

```
trait ML[D <: Distribution[_]] {
  def train(samples: List[D#Domain]): D
}
```

then `D#Domain` cannot be fixed because you're saying that `D` is a subtype of `Distribution[_]` where you really don't care about what `_` actually is. If instead you want to infer the inner type, you could do as follows:

```
trait Measure[T]
trait Random[T]

trait Distribution[A] extends Measure[A] with Random[A] {
  type Domain = A
}

trait Binomial extends Distribution[Int]

trait ML[A, D <: Distribution[A]] {
  def train(samples: List[A]): D    // could be List[D#Domain] now as well
}

object ML {
  implicit object MLBinomial extends ML[Int, Binomial] {
    def train(samples: List[Int]) : Binomial = ???
  }
}
```

**EDIT**: If you don't want to mess around with multiple type parameters, you could also restrict `Domain` to a subtype of `A`. This will type-check and (hopefully) give you what you want. You'd only have to specify `Domain` when defining `Binomial`:

```
trait Distribution[A] extends Measure[A] with Random[A] {
  type Domain <: A
}

trait Binomial extends Distribution[Int] { type Domain = Int }

trait ML[D <: Distribution[_]] {
  def train(samples: List[D#Domain]): D
}

object ML {
  implicit object MLBinomial extends ML[Binomial] {
    def train(samples: List[Int]): Binomial = ???
  }
}
```

Comment: I already know this solution but it doesn't look very satisfying. The compiler should be smart enough to infer the Int type by itself. If only I know how to tell it. Thx anyway.

Comment: I've added another possibility to my former answer. Does this work out for you?

Comment: Note that you can still avoid the redundant domain definition in `Binomial` by introducing a helper trait: `trait ConcreteDistribution[A] extends Distribution[A] { type Domain = A }; trait Binomial extends ConcreteDistribution[Int]`